# compiler issues with simple array program that wont build due to limitations in scope perhaps

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

this is my first question on stack overflow.. Im having compiler issues and wanted to figure out if anyone could help me find out why.

this is the unfortunate error message I recieve every time I attempt to compile.

```
//*************************************************************************
// This program uses array with a for loop control structure to prompt the user to enter their most convenient days of the week to work

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>


int main() {
    int whichDay = 0; 
    array< string, 7> daysOfweek = 
    {
        "sunday", 
        "monday", 
        "tuesday", 
        "wednesday", 
        "thursday", 
        "Friday", 
        "saturday"
    };

    for (size_t x= 0; x< daysOfweek.size(); x++)
    {
        cout << daysOfWeek[x] << endl;
    };

    cout << "enter your work day: " ;
    cin >>  whichDay;
    cout << daysOfWeek[whichDay] += 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:25:10: error: ‘daysOfWeek’ was not declared in this scope
  cout << daysOfWeek[whichDay] += 1
          ^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: A simple typo `daysOfWeek[x]` should not have a capital W

Comment: thank you Michael! I still have a few bugs, it wont let me use = operator for std:: and it wont let me convert argument 1 to std:: however im confused as to how I should change the syntax

Comment: daysOfweek[whichDay] is a string, so +=1 is not valid.

Comment: Running clang_format or another formatting tool will make some typos stand out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask], in particular the error description. You added that as comment, but you should [edit] your question instead. Concerning your kind of question, you first have to extract a [mcve]. That MCVE is supposed to help you find the error yourself and weed out simple questions, it is therefore required and your question considered off-topic without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your issue: `cout << daysOfWeek[whichDay] += 1`.

What would you expect the result of `"monday" += 1` to be?

You probably just want to display the chosen day, so you just need:

```
cout << daysOfWeek[whichDay];
```

Well, you also may want to check that the input value is in the valid range :)

Comment: You're right! thank you for the visual, definitely a goofy mistake

Comment: No problem @jameson, please accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply took a while to figure out how to do that